# Glowing Color in Styled Components Button

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I wanted to achieve a glowing effect exactly like this video.
Pls play this video https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuI91.jpg

Currently, on my code, the glowing looks different and its outside the button.

CODESANDBOX -----> [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-sos1tt?file=/index.js)

```
const LiveNow = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.8rem;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #eb1a30 0%, #ea1973 100%) 0%
    0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  flex-grow: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;
  animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;

  @-webkit-keyframes glowing {
    0% {
      background-color: #eb1a30;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #eb1a30;
    }
    50% {
      background-color: #ea1973;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ea1973;
    }
    100% {
      background-color: #eb1a30;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #eb1a30;
    }
  }
  @keyframes glowing {
    0% {
      background-color: #eb1a30;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #eb1a30;
    }
    50% {
      background-color: #ea1973;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ea1973;
    }
    100% {
      background-color: #eb1a30;
      box-shadow: 0 0 3px #eb1a30;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: What I would suggest, instead of using the box-shadow property to make the glowing effect like the video try changing the opacity of the element. Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-dhqh7y?file=/index.js).

Comment: @Coolis. The video looks different. Its getting dark, not light. Am not sure if opacity is the perfect property to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-cgwn14?file=/index.js).

Using `opacity` is not an option since it also affects the text, but you want only the background to be affected. Instead, use [`rgba`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba) where the last parameter serves as an opacity (i.e., `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)`).

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const LiveNow = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.8rem;
  background: transparent
    linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(235, 26, 48, 1) 0%, rgba(234, 25, 115, 1) 100%)
    0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  flex-grow: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;
  animation: glowing 1300ms infinite;

  @-webkit-keyframes glowing {
    0% {
      background: rgba(235, 26, 48, 0.7);
    }
    50% {
      background: rgba(234, 25, 115, 1);
    }
    100% {
      background: rgba(235, 26, 48, 0.7);
    }
  }
  @keyframes glowing {
    0% {
      background: rgba(235, 26, 48, 0.7);
    }
    50% {
      background: rgba(234, 25, 115, 1);
    }
    100% {
      background: rgba(235, 26, 48, 0.7);
    }
  }
`;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <LiveNow>Live</LiveNow>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```